# In triangle $\triangle ABC,\,$ $\cos 3A + \cos 3B + \cos 3C = 1$. Prove that one angle has to be $120$ degrees.

Tags: geometry

In triangle $\triangle ABC,\,$ $\cos(3A) + \cos(3B) + \cos(3C) = 1$.

Prove that: Either angle $A$ or $B$ or $C = 120$ degrees.
I couldn't even really start this problem any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you use, say, $C=\pi-A-B$, and also use trig identities like addition theorems etc. ? (And what are $A$, $B$, $C$ anyway?

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak: That edit doesn't make sense. You are using same symbols for edges and angles.

Comment: To @emacsdrivesmenuts: Some authors do that, i.e. they use $A$ for a vertex as well as for (inner) angle at the same vertex. We can reedit with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$...

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak: That "some" authors use it doesn't make it any better. An angle is not a point.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$\cos 3A + \cos 3B + \cos 3C =1 \iff \cos 3A + \cos 3B = 1- \cos 3C$.

Now proceed with applying formulas for trigonometric formulas of half-angles, and for sum of two trigonometric functions...

Comment: What kinds of trig identities I am in year 11 and we haven't learned anything besides the pythagorean identity. Are you sure it can't be solved easier? @Anton Vrdoljak

Comment: To @NorbertDomokos: Your Question is obviously connected with trigonometric functions, that is why I suggested formulas regarding half-angles and the sum of two trig. functions...

Answer (score 0):

like emacs said you can solve this with $C = \pi - A - B$ and addition identities. This solution is pretty convoluted so there is probably a much more elagant one though.

WLOG assume C is the largest angle. Since the angles must sum to 180, $3C = 3\pi - (3A + 3B)$. That means that:
$$
cos(3C) = cos(3\pi - (3A + 3B)) \\
=  sin(3\pi)sin((3A + 3B)) + cos(3\pi)cos((3A + 3B)) \\
= -cos(3A+3B)$$
Then from the condition in the problem
$$cos(3A) + cos(3B) - cos(3A+3B) = 1 \\
cos(3A) + cos(3B) + sin(3A)sin(3B) - cos(3A)cos(3B) = 1$$
Since $x+y-xy = -(x-1)(y-1)+1$ (from simon's favorite factoring trick)
$$-(cos(3A)-1)(cos(3B)-1) +1 + sin(3A)sin(3B) = 1\\
(1-cos(3A))(1-cos(3B)) = sin(3A)sin(3B)
$$
Now we can use the double angle identities
$$2sin(\frac{3A}{2})cos(\frac{3A}{2}) \cdot 2sin(\frac{3B}{2})cos(\frac{3B}{2}) = 2sin^2(\frac{3A}{2}) \cdot 2sin^2(\frac{3B}{2}) \\
cos(\frac{3A}{2})cos(\frac{3B}{2}) = sin(\frac{3A}{2})sin(\frac{3B}{2}) \\
cos(\frac{3A}{2})cos(\frac{3B}{2}) - sin(\frac{3A}{2})sin(\frac{3B}{2}) = 0 \\
cos(\frac{3}{2}(A+B)) = 0
$$
Since $C > \frac{\pi}{3}$ is the largest angle, $0 < A+B < \frac{2\pi}{3}$ which means $0 < \frac{3}{2}(A+B) < \pi$. This domain is the range of arccos so we can take arccos of both sides
$$
\frac{3}{2}(A+B) = \frac{\pi}{2} \\
A+B = \frac{\pi}{3} \\
C = \pi - (A+B) = \frac{2\pi}{3} \\
$$